# Java Calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY), will it roll backwards, forwards or unknown?

Tags: java, calendar

Suppose the following code is executed on the 22nd of August 2009 (a Saturday)

```
   Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
   c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
```

`c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)` will return 23.  I'm interested in the conditions is would return 14 (last Sunday, rather than the next Sunday).

Are there any rules associated with the direction Calendar will roll the `DAY_OF_MONTH/YEAR` when `DAY_OF_WEEK` is set?  If so what are they?

Comment: For readers coming to this question after 2014 I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead for the Gregorian calendar use `LocalDate` and `WeekFields`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should always keep the same `WEEK_OF_MONTH` (http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#WEEK_OF_MONTH).  From the documentation:

> When setting or getting the
>   WEEK_OF_MONTH or WEEK_OF_YEAR fields,
>   Calendar must determine the first week
>   of the month or year as a reference
>   point. The first week of a month or
>   year is defined as the earliest seven
>   day period beginning on
>   getFirstDayOfWeek() and containing at
>   least getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() days
>   of that month or year. Weeks numbered
>   ..., -1, 0 precede the first week;
>   weeks numbered 2, 3,... follow it.
>   Note that the normalized numbering
>   returned by get() may be different.
>   For example, a specific Calendar
>   subclass may designate the week before
>   week 1 of a year as week n of the
>   previous year.

Comment: We're talking about `DAY_OF_WEEK` here, I don't see how your answer is related.

Comment: The question is "Are athere any rules associated with the direction Calendar will roll the `DAY_OF_MONTH` when `DAY_OF_WEEK` is set." The answer is: "Whichever direction will keep `WEEK_OF_MONTH` the same."

Answer (score 8):

the following formula returns "current" day in a week in range of [0;6]

```
(d + numberOfDaysInAWeek - firstDayOfWeek) % numberOfDaysInAWeek
```

or add 1 if you would like range [1;7]

```
(d + numberOfDaysInAWeek - firstDayOfWeek) % numberOfDaysInAWeek + 1
```

`d` is what `Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)` returns

to get first day of a week, subtract formula's result from current date. The following code does it:

```
final int currentDayOfWeek = (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + 7 - cal.getFirstDayOfWeek()) % 7;
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -currentDayOfWeek);
```

Answer (score 7):

## Using java.time

The modern approach is with the java.time classes that supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

The java.time classes are much easier to work with. In particular, they remove the ambiguity raised in the Question. You can explicitly ask either for the *earlier* Sunday or for the *later* Sunday.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

The `Month` enum provides a dozen pre-defined objects, one for each month of the year. These enum objects are safer to use, but you can instead use a plain number for the month. Unlike the legacy classes, these months have sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2009 , Month.AUGUST, 22 );
```

The [`TemporalAdjuster`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) interface provides for manipulation of date-time values. The [`TemporalAdjusters`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) class (note the plural `s`) provides several handy implementations.

The `previous` & `next` adjusters exclude the date itself from consideration. The `previousOrSame` & `nextOrSame` methods return the date in question if it is indeed the desired day-of-week.

The `DayOfWeek` enum provides seven pre-defined objects, one for each day of the week.

```
LocalDate previousSunday = localDate.with( TemporalAdjusters.previous ( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ));
LocalDate previousOrSameSunday = localDate.with( TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame ( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ));

LocalDate nextSunday = localDate.with( TemporalAdjusters.next ( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ));
LocalDate nextOrSameSunday = localDate.with( TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame ( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ));
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ("localDate: " + localDate + " ( " + localDate.getDayOfWeek ().getDisplayName ( TextStyle.FULL, Locale.US )  + " )");
System.out.println ("previousSunday: " + previousSunday );
System.out.println ("nextSunday: " + nextSunday );
```

> localDate: 2009-08-22 ( Saturday )
>
> previousSunday: 2009-08-16
>
> nextSunday: 2009-08-23

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Great detail, exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It depends, actually. Consider the following Java code. It is actually quite simple and I expect it to print the monday preceding 2011-09-18, that is 2011-09-12:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
System.out.printf("First day of week: %d%n%n", calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek());

calendar.set(2011, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 18);
System.out.printf("Starting day: %tF%n", calendar);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
System.out.printf("Last monday: %tF%n%n", calendar);

calendar.set(2011, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 18);
System.out.printf("Starting day: %tF (week %d)%n",
        calendar, calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
System.out.printf("Last monday: %tF (week %d)%n", calendar,
        calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
```

But in fact the result is a bit different:

```
First day of week: 2

Starting day: 2011-09-18
Last monday: 2011-09-19

Starting day: 2011-09-18 (week 37)
Last monday: 2011-09-12 (week 37)
```

In other words, the result depends on whether my calendar knows that I might be interested in the week. The result actually changes if I query `WEEK_OF_YEAR`!

Answer (score 1):

From the [Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html):

> If there is any conflict in calendar field values, Calendar gives priorities to calendar fields that have been set more recently. The following are the default combinations of the calendar fields. The most recent combination, as determined by the most recently set single field, will be used.
>
> For the date fields:

```
 YEAR + MONTH + DAY_OF_MONTH
 YEAR + MONTH + WEEK_OF_MONTH + DAY_OF_WEEK
 YEAR + MONTH + DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH + DAY_OF_WEEK
 YEAR + DAY_OF_YEAR
 YEAR + DAY_OF_WEEK + WEEK_OF_YEAR
```

I interpret this to mean that given that you're setting day of week, it will end up being combined with week of month or week of year in order to produce the actual date and time.

Answer (score 1):

You should also check what is the first day in a week.
I also thought it is always Sunday, but this depend on local settings, and in my case
Monday is the first day in week. Setting Sunday as first day of the week fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the first day of the week:

```
 /**
 * Gets what the first day of the week is; e.g., <code>SUNDAY</code> in the U.S.,
 * <code>MONDAY</code> in France.
 *
 * @return the first day of the week.
 * @see #setFirstDayOfWeek(int)
 * @see #getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()
 */
public int getFirstDayOfWeek()
{
    return firstDayOfWeek;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this method.

```
public Integer whichDayOfWeek(Calendar calendar) {
            if (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.MONDAY) {
                return 1;
            } else if (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.TUESDAY) {
                return 2;
            } else if (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.WEDNESDAY) {
                return 3;
            } else if (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.THURSDAY) {
                return 4;
            } else if (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.FRIDAY) {
                return 5;
            } else if (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY) {
                return 6;
            } else if (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
                return 7;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: this doesn't address the poster's question at all