# how to get the specific time in java

Tags: java

I am trying to get the current time in android app.
here is my code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date date = new Date();
cal.setTime(date);
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
```

today is Wednesday. the output should be 3. but it is 4.

can someone help me with this?

Comment: it has been asked and answered here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689435/java-calendar-using-calendar-day-of-week-to-get-the-first-and-the-last-dates-for

Comment: This is a duplicate question, but also, have you considered that java/android thinks Sunday = 1, Monday = 2, etc.? So if you want Wednesday to be 3, just subtract 1 from your answer