# Calendar set DAY_OF_WEEK not staying in current week

Tags: java, calendar

I have this code:

```
Calendar current = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
current.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
current.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
```

Today is Friday, Dec. 6. When I run it, I expect that the current week should be Monday, Dec 2->Sunday, Dec. 8, and `current` should now be set to Dec. 8. However, it is set to Dec. 1. Isn't that breaking the `setFirstDayOfWeek` call that I made?

Comment: As far as I can see, there isn't any documentation saying that when you set the DAY_OF_WEEK it will stay within the same week. Do you have some documentation you're thinking of?

Comment: @JonSkeet I interpreted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319473/java-calendar-setcalendar-day-of-week-calendar-sunday-will-it-roll-backwards to indicate that it would. The link to the docs in that answer is unfortunately broken, so I can't verify that it's correct.

Comment: @rgettman It seems to me that calling `setFirstDayOfWeek` should cause `Calendar` to treat that as the first day of the week when calculating.

Comment: That answer is talking about setting WEEK_OF_YEAR or WEEK_OF_MONTH - you're not setting either of those fields.

Comment: @JonSkeet The other answers also indicate the same thing about DAY_OF_WEEK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) )                       // Get today’s date as seen by the people of a particular region (time zone).
         .with( TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) ) // Move to the next Monday, unless today is already a Monday.
```

## java.time

You are using terribly troublesome old `Calendar` class that is now obsolete legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit, as the default may be changed at any moment *during runtime* by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Or specify a date. You may set the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 ) ;  // Years use sane direct numbering (1986 means year 1986). Months use sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year. Tip: Use these `Month` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere integer number to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
```

## Day of week

You can get the day-of-week represented as a `DayOfWeek` enum object.

```
DayOfWeek dow = ld.getDayOfWeek() ;
```

To move to another date, use a [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) implementation found in [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) class.

```
LocalDate nextOrSameMonday = ld.with( TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) ) ;
```

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed writeup. This was over four years ago, so I'm glad Java has finally worked out a better system for dealing with time.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround for this has been to use [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) (of course). This works for me because JodaTime assumes that weeks start on Monday. Unfortunately, there is no way to change the day that JodaTime treats as the first day of the week.

```
    DateTime dt = new DateTime();
    dt = dt.withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY);
    Calendar current = dt.toGregorianCalendar();
```

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).