# Convert Calendar set DAY_OF_WEEK to use TemporalAdjusters

Tags: java, java-time, dayofweek, java.util.calendar

I have some legacy code like this

```
        final Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.setTime(today);
        // changed on May-03-2004
        //cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, cal.getFirstDayOfWeek());
        if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -6);
        } else {
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
        }
        //System.out.println("Begin of cycle: " + cal.getTime());
```

And I would like to convert it to use java.time TemporalAdjuster class to hopefully make it more readable.

But I am not really sure how to interpret https://stackoverflow.com/a/1319484/242042 to make the behaviour match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `today` really is today's date, then the Java Time API version, using [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html), would be:

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();

TemporalAdjuster adjuster = TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY);
LocalDate monday = today.with(adjuster);

System.out.println(today + " -> " + monday);
```

*Sample Output*

```
2020-02-01 -> 2020-01-27
```

`2020-02-01` is a Saturday, and `2020-01-27` is the preceding Monday.

Answer (score 1):

### DayOfWeek implements TemporalAdjuster

I think that your code attempts to set the `Calendar` object to Monday of the same ISO week, that is, the Monday preceding today if today is not already a Monday (this will not always be the result in all locales, though). It’s really simple when you know how.

```
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.of(2020, Month.FEBRUARY, 2);
    LocalDate monday = today.with(DayOfWeek.MONDAY);
    System.out.println("Monday of the same week is " + monday + ", a " + monday.getDayOfWeek());
```

Output from this snippet is:

> Monday of the same week is 2020-01-27, a MONDAY

`LocalDate` always uses the ISO calendar, in which Monday is the first day of the week, so `today.with(DayOfWeek.MONDAY)` gives you the Monday of the same week, in other words, the previous Monday of today is not already a Monday. `GregorianCalendar` used the week definition of the default locale, which caused a bit of complication in the code to make sure it would also behave correctly in locales where Sunday is the first day of the week. `LocalDate` behaves the same in all locales, which is one of the reasons why the code using `LocalDate` is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after playing around and trying different combinations in https://repl.it/@trajano/setCal

The code translates to

```java
  public static LocalDate doIt(LocalDate todayDate) {
    final LocalDate c2;
    if (todayDate.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY) {
      c2 = todayDate.minusDays(6);
    } else {
      c2 = todayDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
    }
    return c2;

  }
```

Comment: Why have an `if` statement? Wouldn't `with(previousOrSame(MONDAY))` do the same as `minusDays(6)` for a Sunday?

Comment: but it seems like you're right I just tried to comment it out on my Repl, thanks that simplifies things.